# "Replace all" in project / selection not working?

Tags: netbeans, replace

In Netbeans 7.2, after selecting packages or a project and opening the dialog `Edit->Replace` or `Edit->Replace in projects`, I can't find a button or option to replace all occurrences. The only way I found is to open a file, select `Edit->Replace` and then "Replace all", but this obviously applies only to the current file.

How to find & replace in a custom selection over files, packages, projects, ...?

#### Edit

The "Search Results" window looks like this after `Edit->Replace in projects...->Find`:[image: Search Results window]

There is no button or menu to do the replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `Edit -> Replace (in Projects)` a `Search Results` window appears, listing all matches available for your selection.

But now you have to click on **`Replace xy matches`** for completion.

Note that the `Search Results` window must be large enough so that all buttons show up!

Comment: Is this your whole **Search Results** Window? Two icons are missing on the left side (and at this size the replace button is not visible). If you increase the height of the window, are there more symbols visible (you can also double click on the **Search Results** tab to make it fullscreen)?

Comment: Indeed, the button appears when making the window larger.
Not very nice of Netbeans...
Thank you!

Comment: I think this is more a problem of space than of netbeans :-)

Comment: I mean to hide essential controls because of lack of space is not very helpful.